# Proving the Conclusion

Tags: logic

[image]Derivations
Prove that the following arguments are valid.ANSWSER IS POSTED

1. (Q → ¬P), (¬Q → ¬P) ⊢ ¬P

notes:
⊢ stands for the conclusion. so basically, I am trying to prove how -P is a true/proper conclusion for (Q → ¬P), (¬Q → ¬P). To do this, I know inference rules need to be used, like MP, MTP, ADJ, ADD, DN, etc,.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with the "etc" in the list of rules... See [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination)

Comment: Are you in a math class or a philosophy class. Each one may teach slightly different. Logic is not just logic where it is all the same thing. There are distinct kinds that are not the same. Textbooks also may differ on the inference rules you are allowed to use. Furthermore math uses different terminology on some of the same rules that philosophy uses: I.e., contraposition in math = transposition in philosophy. What did you try? You need to try something and fail and ask where you went wrong.  The proof for this can consist of using four inference rules to get to ~P

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA and Logikal You say that there are limitations on the number of rules that are allowed, but does that actually effect the realm of possibilities that you're operating in, so is it a different math or is that more of a practice thing, making it either easier by not overwhelming with options or harder because you have to derive higher level options yourself?

Comment: @haxor789 I see what you are saying, but there are two things to realize.  Most classes have limited rules as well as the textbooks they require.  Sure there is a subject called Mathematical Logic & not just LOGIC as most people around here call it. Philosophy teaches it differently which people ignore or don’t realize the difference.  Mathematical logic tends to use Natural Deduction rules where philosophy doesn’t. Many of the rules go by different names & some rules do not appear at all like disjunction elimination in Philosophy.In math you have less rules & have to derive higher level rules

Comment: @Logikal I mean I get what you're saying and that it might be confusing to have mixed up terminology and you're probably right about that. That being said I'm not convinced we're actually talking about a different kind of logic and not just bickering about whether it's called 2+5 or 5+2. If I should be wrong could you show a source that explains how you can not formulate this kind of logic in terms of boolean algebra and vice versa?

Comment: @haxor789 You are confused. Modern logic today is all mathematical logic by default.  Mathematical logic was not around 200 years ago or prior to that. There were other types of LOGIC.  Aristotelian logic predates Mathematical logic by thousands of years. The concepts & rules are not identical.  There are different types of Mathematical logic systems named specifically as K, T, L and so on.  So within mathematical logic there are distinctions.  There is no LOGIC that is universal everywhere.  The system matters and the type matters.

Comment: @Logikal  By a different logic I mean whether you're dealing with a boolean algebra or whether you don't have axioms like assozatiion, distribution, transistiveness and so on. Like are you operating on the same mathematical construct. And as far as I can see, you are doing that so even if these rules are not given to you, you could still proof that they exist because of the relation between those axioms.

Comment: @haxor789 No I am not doing Boolean algebra. That is not taught in philosophy. Mathematical logic teaches this topic differently which is my point. Some of the concepts are distinct from the other. You are STILL behaving as all there is is mathematical logic & nothing else exists. This is wrong.  Philosophy doesn’t begin with axioms nor assumptions not in the premises. I can use premises directly with the rules of inference to reach the conclusion with zero assumptions or axioms.  Assumptions & axioms is a math thing. They are not necessary to prove problems each time. In math they are.

Comment: And what are those "rules" but axioms? And no math doesn't need any assumption beyond the axioms the rest follows straight from them. But apparently your methods make lots of assumption because they only want to show the validity so they can already infer things by setting certain values to true and checking what that would do. Also that's not the point the question is are the rules/axioms or however you want to call them different so that you're dealing on idk a different topology or with more than 2 truth values or not, because if they aren't then you probably can translate these languages

Comment: got the answer. posting it on the question

Comment: In logic there're many different systems using different rules/axioms such as yours, natural deduction (Fitch nested column style + Gentzen tree style), and Hilbert axiomatic system with MP as the only inference rule. But whatever system you use, the basic trick is same. In this case it is proof by negation as the [old saying](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html) goes: *To speak of the false is to reveal the true...*

Comment: What rule set did you use? What textbook?  This is not Natural Deduction nor Copi rules. Why is it so long? Could you not solve it in less than 11 lines? I did it in 6.

Comment: @Logikal it is philosophical logic. im literally in a summer course and everything is so crammed I'm just trying to understand it. someone in my class sent the answer that's way more simple and only took 8 lines.

Comment: What textbook are you using?  What is CDJ?

Comment: @Logikal my lecturer uses the software called carnap. so the book is literally called the carnap book. CDJ stands for conditional to disjunction.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the material implication rule I used to solve with a different name. With the rules there was no need to make any assumptions. The proof should be shorter. The rules would directly solve it alone.

Answer (score 2):

There's more than one way to skin this cat. If you are using Fitch rules, then you have a direct proof using the following rule of disjunction elimination:

```
A v B
A ⊢ C
B ⊢ C
------
C
```

So, just prove Q v ¬Q, then assume Q and prove ¬P by modus ponens, then assume ¬Q and prove ¬P by modus ponens, and then use the Fitch rule of disjunction elimination.

Or, if you prefer, you can use an indirect proof by assuming P, then prove ¬Q by modus tollens, then prove Q by modus tollens, and hence since your assumption of P proves a contradiction, you have ¬P by reductio.

Answer (score 1):

One must know what inference rules are in play. This is super important to the proof.  I will name Copi rules one can use to solve with zero assumptions.

1. ```
     (Q -> ~P) [Premise 1]
   ```
2. ```
     (~Q  -> ~P)  [Premise 2]        / therefore   ~P [Conclusion]
   ```
3. ```
     ***.                 Line 2 Transposition
   ```
4. ```
     ***.                 Lines 1, 4 Hypothetical syllogism
   ```
5. ```
     ***.                 Line 5.  Material Implication
   ```
6. ```
      ****.               Line 6.  Tautology
   ```

QED.

Proof done.  ***The conclusion does not belong on another line.**** The conclusion appears offset on the same line as the final premise. This is the proper format which is easy to read. All of the work below the premises should be the problem solver's work and that work is identified by this format.  If anything goes wrong below line 2 then the problem solver is at fault (in this case ME).  The format separates what was actually given by someone else and the work of the person solving the problem displays. That is an important distinction to make for accountability.

I did not show the work of course because this is about UNDERSTANDING a what we are doing not just getting the problem correct for homework, quiz, etc.

In all your getting get understanding.

Do not just memorize and fake your way through a course.  If you were allowed to use the rules I mentioned the work should be easy.

If you are using natural deduction rules others have shown paths you can take.

I showed the Copi rules and how they differ and can get the same conclusion with zero axioms or assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess on stackoverflow you'd get closed for asking homework questions but as I couldn't find rules against that (yet, correct me if I'm wrong), let's do this logical sudoku real quick:

Assuming that this operator ⊢  stand for equality of tautology or something like that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective

Now validity of a statement means that if the premises were true the conclusion must also be true. So it's essentially:
Premise1∧Premise2 → Conclusion.

((Q → ¬P) ∧ (¬Q → ¬P)) → ¬P

Now you can apply a [Simplification of disjunctive antecedents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplification_of_disjunctive_antecedents) (* see proof of why that can be applied further down in this answer)

((Q ∨ ¬Q) → ¬P) → ¬P

Now (Q ∨ ¬Q) is obviously true, so there's no harm done adding another true statement with an and due to the fact that True And Statement would still obviously have the same truth value as the statement itself.

(Q ∨ ¬Q) ∧ ((Q ∨ ¬Q) → ¬P) → ¬P

Now if we look closely at this we could see that his is modus ponens and therefore a tautology. Which can be made more clear by replacing (Q ∨ ¬Q) with idk a symbol R of the same truth value:

R ∧ (R → ¬P) → ¬P

Where as said R ∧ (R → ¬P) is ¬P due to MP, which concludes this proof.

---

And for the other one (that is now no longer part of the question, but was when this answer was written...):
(Q → ¬R), (¬P → R) ⊢ (¬P → ¬Q)

One can use the [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) A → B = ¬B → ¬A.  So:

(Q → ¬R) ∧ (¬P → R) → (¬P → ¬Q)

Becomes:

(R → ¬Q) ∧ (¬P → R) → (¬P → ¬Q)

And from there it follows from the [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Formal_properties) property of the Material conditional that ¬P → ¬Q at which it again follows from itself which also concludes that it's valid.

So you should obviously look up what was done and why you are allowed to do that ;)

Update: A practice problem to study is still a home work ;)

**Proof that you can rephrase SDA in terms of the copi rules** (assuming those are your constraints)
Anyway well you need to rephrase these logical operations in terms of your [equivalence and interference rules](https://www.cs.mtsu.edu/%7Exyang/3080/derivationrules.html):

So for example you'd need to show that
(A ∨ B) → C is the same as A → C ∧ B → C :
So here you would apply imp to get:

¬(A ∨ B) ∨ C

From there you would apply De Morgan to the parenthesis:

(¬A ∧ ¬B) ∨ C

Assuming that the distributive law which isn't listed in the previous list but in this one:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus

Is part of the derivation laws. You can write that as:

(¬A ∨ C) ∧ (¬B ∨ C)

Which if you can interpret as two imp statements connected with an AND:

(A → C) ∧ (B → C)

So the Simplification of disjunctive antecedents can indeed be applied even with the derivation laws of the propositional logic. Though you'd go the other way around, but as these are equivalence relations that shouldn't be a problem. I leave it to your practice to fit that into the right form or was that your problem?

For the Contraposition there's a nice simple proof on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition#Simple_proof_by_definition_of_a_conditional

which should suffice the derivation rules.

And the transitive relation in proposition logic is apparently called [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) which also has a prove written in the formal language.

Comment: It isn't homework, it is a practice problem for studying. Also, this isn't the format that I am looking for, but I appreciate your response!

Comment: Updated my post. Not in formal logic but that shouldn't be too hard from there.

Comment: The goal was to get ~p.  You do not show that.  You show SDA follows.  By the way which textbook would you think shows SDA as an inference rule?  I would venture to say zero.  I am glad you broke down SDA using some common inference rules used in actual textbooks but SDA was not what was to be proved. It looks like you took the conclusion to be part of each premise and then you tried to prove it.  Where did you learn that?  What textbooks teach the method you used?  Or did you just Google this?

Comment: @Logikal Apparently SDA is called "Disjunction Elimination" and my proof actually gets you to  ¬P after applying SDA/DE and Modus Ponen or mp. And yes I'm more familiar with the boolean algebra than the proposition logic, but they're not doing something inherently different by calling it different names... And what matters is the logic not the nomenclature. And if there's no consistency in textbooks then that's doubly important.

Comment: @haxor789 No disjunctive elimination is very different from SDA conceptually.  They are not identical but perhaps they get you to the same place.  The method is super important.  Most systems use a Fitch style proof method.  You can Google that to see what it looks like. The competition is the Gentzen style proof system which you can also Google. The reasoning you do is not reliable because you get the conclusion— the thing is can you do it all the time with 100 percent accuracy?  So getting the answer correct is not the main goal. Is the method reliable IS.

Comment: If you look at the formal logic representation of DE then it its identical to SDA. At best you can argue that the DE formula uses additional information, which I've proven could also be generated from the premises itself using derivation rules. So they don't just end at the same place they do the same thing. So speaking in CS lingo that's algorithm in pseudocode while OP is writing code in Java and apparently there's also C++, but in the end they implement the same concept. So yes that is 100% accurate. I'm not guessing. Unless they utilize different math the method doesn't matter.

Comment: @haxor789 No method matters like I said because we want 100 percent accuracy. By method I am not referring to the layout or system the proof is completed with.  DE requires an assumption to be made.  Most of mathematical logic requires assumption to to start a proof whereas philosophy does not.  So you make an assumption & I do not means we are not doing the same thing! That clearly means we are not doing identical things.  CS uses mathematical logic so I am not sure how you do not know the natural deduction rules. You seem to also confuse doing the same thing & getting the same answer.

Comment: Where would I be making any assumptions? So far I think you've just not grasped the proof. Do you have a short overview of where someone knowledgeable in your theory explains it? Cause you seem to be confused and that confuses me.

Comment: @haxor789 do you understand the disjunctive elimination rule requires an assumption to be made or not?  Is there a disjunctive in any of the original premises?  That would be a NO. How did you convert the implication into a either or? What inference rules is that. In natural deduction there is no rule that converts if  . . Then to either . . Or.  You don’t know what an assumption is now? Was it in the premises?  Look at Bubble’s answer that is the form of disjunctive elimination.  It is not in the original premises. Philosophy doesn’t have a rule named disjunction elimination.

Comment: @haxor789 I meant Bumbles answer above not Bubble. You do understand that I am referring to how philosophy teaches reasoning versus how math teaches reasoning correct?  They are not identical methods and the terminology does not always mean the same thing. For instance in mathematical logic you have a rule named contraposition this is not used in philosophy as such because there are propositions contraposition does not work.  In math clearly you have no idea about that.  Contraposition goes back to Aristotle and his logic which was NOT math. The rule instead is called TRANSPOSITION which works

Comment: @haxor789 I also noticed you really don’t know any inference rules.  There are two sets you need to be aware of: one set  is called Copi Rules which is what most philosophy texts use & then there is Natural Deduction set of rules. You don’t seem to be aware of this. You seem to think you can just Google stuff and use it.  You can’t combine the sets! Most problems will use one set and not both. The rules are limited depending on the set you use.

Comment: @Logikal You make the assumption because you want to show the validity, therefore you assume the truthfulness of the premises to show that the conclusion would also be true. You can already use that in order to simplify the statement as you don't care about the general case but just a specific one, but it's not that you'd need to. You could also make the assumption the very last step to prove validity. And apparently I'm using the copi rules, at least I do not apply anything that is not a set of these rules. And how they are named and where they come from doesn't matter to logic but to history

Comment: @haxor789 you are mixing rules from the two sets. There is no disjunction elimination rule in the Copi rules. The closest to it is called a conditional proof specifically but all assumptions under Copi are called conditional proofs. There is no assumption allowed if that rule is not given. Usually Copi has 19 rules where assumptions are NOT ALLOWED at all. I know why assumptions are made but they are not needed in philosophy. In Math apparently they are required which shows a distinction between math & philosophy. I answer the OP  question using Copi rules in a separate post above.

Comment: @Logikal I reread the stuff and I need to give you a little more credit than I originally intended. I still think your bickering on terminology is mindless sophistry and apparently wikipedia already decided to not give a shit whether it's contraposition or transposition and uses both names. That being said I like your proof and how it doesn't really on imputing a value. I still disagree though on your DE not being part of copi as you can build SDA/DE within copi rules. Also I'm unsure about the nature of this construct ((Q ∨ ¬Q) → ¬P) → ¬P does it need inputs or isn't that already a tautology?

Comment: I mean your could for the sake of argument add a tautology and make ((Q ∨ ¬Q) → ¬P) → ¬P become (Q ∨ ¬Q) ∧ ((Q ∨ ¬Q) → ¬P) → ¬P and then you could without changing anything call R:= Q ∨ ¬Q and you'd end up with R ∧ (R→ ¬P), which is the classical example of MP and therefore a tautology without making any assumptions.

Comment: @haxor789 you look as if you are using some kind of axiom system that is different than the typical proof systems.  If you don't require assumptions then it appears one must know the axioms by heart or else there will be problems solving a question.  Math & computer science uses Mathematical logic but the format used for programming itself looks different. Typically programing logic looks more Gentzen style of proofs rather than Fitch. I would never break things down as you suggest I. Philosophy. I would strictly use Copi rules with zero axioms & zero assumptions for most cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137509/discussion-between-haxor789-and-logikal).